# Error :'int' object is not subscriptable, while displying output from SQLite to Python code

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I am using SQLite in Python to store and retrieve data.

This is my Python code:

```
# Read API key
API_KEY = os.environ["API_KEY"]
# Create bot object
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

# Connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect('message_tracker.db', check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()

# Create messages table if it does not exist
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages
             (group_id integer, user_id integer, message_text text, message_date DATETIME)''')

# Function to get message count for a given time period
def get_message_count(chat_id, start_date, end_date):
    c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM messages WHERE group_id=? AND message_date BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY user_id", (chat_id, start_date, end_date))
    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:
      output = f"\n\t{row[0]}: {row[1]}"
      print(output)
    return output

# Handler for '/dcount' command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['dcount'])
def handle_daily_count(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    date_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    message_count = get_message_count(chat_id, user_id, date_today, date_today)
    print(date_today)
    print(chat_id)
    print(user_id)
  
    bot.reply_to(message, f"{message.chat.title} - {message.from_user.first_name}: {message_count} messages today.")

# Handler for '/wcount' command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['wcount'])
def handle_weekly_count(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    date_today = datetime.now()
    start_date = (date_today - timedelta(days=date_today.weekday())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = (date_today + timedelta(days=6-date_today.weekday())).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    message_count = get_message_count(chat_id, user_id, start_date, end_date)
    bot.reply_to(message, f"{message.chat.title} - {message.from_user.first_name}: {message_count} messages this week.")

# Handler for '/mcount' command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['mcount'])
def handle_monthly_count(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    date_today = datetime.now()
    start_date = date_today.replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = date_today.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=32)
    end_date = (end_date.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    message_count = get_message_count(chat_id, user_id, start_date, end_date)
    bot.reply_to(message, f"{message.chat.title} - {message.from_user.first_name}: {message_count} messages this month.")

# Handler for tracking messages
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def track_message(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    message_text = message.text
    if len(message_text.split()) > 2:
        message_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print(message_date)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO messages VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (chat_id, user_id, message_text, message_date))
        conn.commit()
        print(message_date)
        print(chat_id)
        print(user_id)
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Please use more than 3 words.")

# Start the bot
bot.polling()
```

I have added print to check what I am storing into the database, which is showing the correct information.

I am able to store data successfully, but when I try to get counts, it showing below error

```
  File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/home/runner/SupremeBotpy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/runner/SupremeBotpy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/home/runner/SupremeBotpy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/runner/SupremeBotpy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 148, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/runner/SupremeBotpy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 91, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/SupremeBotpy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 6428, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "main.py", line 45, in handle_daily_count
    output += f"{row[0]}: {row[1]}"
```

Comment: Why are you including the time in your date/time conversion?  There aren't going to be any records that are between the current TIME and the current TIME.

Comment: @TimRoberts i tried without time as well like this `date_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` but still getting zero

Comment: But you're creating the records with the time, right?  Remember sqlite doesn't really have types.  Those are strings.  You may need `BETWEEN '2023-03-24' AND '2023-03-25'`.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for help now it showing result, but i am facing one more issue, I am trying to see all users with their msg count but i am not getting how to show those. I tried with `def get_message_count(chat_id, start_date, end_date):
    c.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM messages WHERE group_id=? AND message_date BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY user_id", (chat_id, start_date, end_date))
    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:
      output = f"\n\t{row[0]}: {row[1]}"
      print(output)
    return output` 
But getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I have updated question with error

Comment: Well, you included everything in the traceback except the exception, so we don't know what the error actually was.  And, the line of code it shows is not in the code you showed us.